# Azure dreamsparkサブスクリプション上にTomcatアプリケーションを構築するには

Tags: azure

Azure (dreamsparkサブスクリプション利用)で上にTomcat、MySQL、JSP&サーブレットを利用してアプリケーションを構築したいと思います。

リソースとして何を選択するべきかご教授ください。

現状試したのは

1. Webアプリ+MySQL、アプリケーション設定でTomcatを選択してもTomcatのホーム画面が表示されない(404エラーになる)
2. リソースからApache Tomcat 8を選択し、KuduからsiteextentionにてphpMyAdminの導入を試みたが"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."エラーが表示される

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Azure WEBアプリケーションはAzure用にカスタマイズされたWindows上で動作するサービスです。Windows上で動作するWEBサービスは、大抵の場合はAzure WEBサービスでも動作しますが、独特のノウハウが必要になります。

1.についてはどのような手順で作成したのか分からないので回答できません。少なくともテンプレートからApatch Tomcatを選択する分には正常に表示されるようになりますよね。

2.についてはWEBアプリケーションから選択することが出来るMySQLサービスはSuccessBricks, IncがZure上で提供するクラウドサービスです。データベースの管理にはSuccessBricks, Incのツールを使用する必要があります。

もしLinuxでの運用経験を生かしてMicrosoft Azure上にサービスを構築したいのであれば、WEBアプリケーションではなく、仮想マシン上でLinuxを動作させることをお勧めします。